# Drawn object doesn't clear previous rectangle after key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, keylistener

My code will not clear the previous rectangle. I thought by using the getRect() and then using repaint() in my keyPressed() method, that would solve the problem.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Rectangle extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

private int height;
private int width;
private int x;
private int y;
private Graphics2D g2;



public Rectangle(int width, int height,int x, int y)
{
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

   JLabel label = new JLabel();


    setSize(1000,1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


    label.addKeyListener(this);
    label.setFocusable(true);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.addKeyListener(this);
    this.add(label);
    setVisible(true);
    label.requestFocusInWindow();

}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{   

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        g2.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
        y = y + 5;
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        g2.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
        x = x - 5;
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        g2.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
        y = y - 5;
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        g2.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        x = x + 5;
        repaint();
    }
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}




public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);

}

}
```

Test Method:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(400,200,500,500);

}
}
```

Comment: Don't override paint and draw on a JFrame directly. Instead use a JPanel that is added to a JFrame. Look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html. Also could you post an image of what is happening right now that is undesirable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setVisible(true)` should be last code line in public `Rectangle(...`, because you added `JComponent`s to the already visible Swing GUI.
2. `JFrame` isn't focusable for `KeyEvent`, by default.
3. put `JPanel` to `JFrame`'s `CENTER` area, by default: `myFrame.add(myPanel)`.
4. override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel` instead of setting for `JFrame` size; sizing should be intialized by calling `myFrame.pack()`.
5. `JPanel` must be focusable for receiving an `KeyEvent`, `setFocusable(true)`; use KeyBindings instead of hunting for focus in `JComponent` hierarchy.
6. override `paintComponent` for `JPanel`; 1st code line should be `super.paintComponent`, otherwise painting artifacts will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add more detail?
From what I can see, you may want to make a clear button & method.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to clear the rectangle with a button, but rather when I press the arrow keys. If I press up, I want the rectangle to move up and the previous rectangle to be cleared. Does that help?

Comment: Oh, is the rectangle repeating itself?